# Function TestMain didn't run

Tags: go, testing

Seems like my func TestMain didn't run

I have 2 file in my test folder `/_test`. One is `/main_test.go`, another one is `/api_city_find_all_test.go`.

I run the second one and there's panic error says that i got nil pointer i tried printout something in my /main_test.go in func TestMain but it didn't print anything, seems like the main_test.go didn't work/run

anyone can help me with this?

**main_test.go**

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {

  fmt.Print("TEST@@")

  os.Chdir("../../../")

  boot.Bootstrap()

  rajaongkir.Register()

  os.Exit(m.Run())
}
```

I run
**api_city_find_all_test.go**

```
func TestApiCityFindAllTest(t *testing.T) {
  goreq := libraries.Request("http://localhost:8181").Post([]string{"rajaongkir/city/findAll"}, nil, `{}`)

  req, _ := goreq.MakeRequest()
  resp := httptest.NewRecorder()

  fmt.Print("TEST!!")

  utilities.Globals.Router.ServeHTTP(resp, req)

  respBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

  t.Log(string(respBody))

  assert.NotEqual(t, "null", string(respBody))
}
```

I expect the "TEST!!" in api_rajaongkir_city_find_all_test.go and "TEST@@" in main_test.go are printed but just "TEST!!" shown up, it means the main_Test.go didn't run

Answer (score 3):

The [`TestMain`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main) function is local to a test package.

> If a test file contains a function:
>
> ```
> func TestMain(m *testing.M)
> ```
>
> then the generated test will call `TestMain(m)` instead of running the tests directly.

You have to make sure that both files define the same package or define `TestMain(m)` in both files.

Comment: i confused, there should not be more than one TestMain in the same package right? imean i already define that both files in the same package _test

Comment: Yes. Have you tried adding the `TestMain(m)` to *api_city_find_all_test.go* once? It should fail compilation then...